# Missing Image name in the task manager

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, task-manager, visual-studio-2008

Recently I face the following problem .

When I open the visual studio (Design view ) .it has hanged up .

I go to the task manager to check what's happened.

I find two things :

---

1- Can't find the `image name(process name)` even in the column to select from !!

2- It consumes about `338,608k RAM` and 25 from CPU !!

I want to know how to show the image name  again because my windows 7 is 64 and i want to determine the type of the process. and i want to know why this happened

Comment: Install this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx  use it and let us know if you are able to see the process name now.

Comment: I have looked at the task manager select columns dialog and I can't see process name. In earlier versions of Windows it was there but you could not deselect it. Perhaps you have resized it to zero width or moved the column to the right.

Comment: @ta.speot.is : where i can find this check  please??

Comment: then how to restore it again ?